# Bindings not applied to dynamically-loaded xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, xamlreader

I'm using `XamlReader` successfully to load a xaml file and create a `FrameworkElement` to work with.

The xaml I'm loading has binding expressions in it such as:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContextTextProperty}" />
```

If I place the FrameworkElement I get back from `XamlReader.Load()` into a WPF window, the binding all works fine.

However, in this case I'm using [Laurent Bugnion's excellent article on creating PNGs from WPF/XAML](http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2008/10/10/converting-and-customizing-xaml-to-png-with-server-side-wpf.aspx). Since the result of `XamlReader.Load()` is written directly to a PNG via a `VisualBrush`, it seems the necessary mechanics of WPF to invoke binding expressions are bypassed.

This leads me to believe that the actual bindings aren't really being invoked just by calling `XamlReader.Load()`, or that they're not working because of something I don't know about to do with there not being a visual tree until you add the `FrameworkElement` to an existing visual tree or something.

Is there something I can do to ensure these bindings are invoked?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I do think a layout and render pass is required for a View to be writeable as an image and that is possible only if we load it onto a visual tree. Correct me if I am wrong. Although XamlWriter with FlowDocument is a little different story .

Comment: @AngelWPF I managed to solve it and have posted an answer below. It does seem to be behaving how I want, so providing there isn't some naive mistake I've made, I'm going to go with it. I can't tell you how relieved I am to get this working...

Answer (score 5):

I FIXED IT!!

Ahem, allow me to explain...

I have no idea how I got to it now, but I found a helpful-sounding article on MSDN regarding [Initialization for Objects Not in an Object Tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788731.aspx).

In it I found the following code example:

```
Button b = new Button();
b.BeginInit();
b.Background = Brushes.Blue;
b.Width = b.Height = 200;
b.EndInit();
b.Measure(paperSize);
b.Arrange(new Rect(paperSize));
b.UpdateLayout();
```

I looked at the (again, excellent) example from Laurent that I mentioned in the question above, and customised the use of `XamlReader` as follows:

```
var element = (FrameworkElement)XamlReader.Load(xamlInput);

element.BeginInit();
element.DataContext = dataContext;

...

element.Measure(renderingSize);
element.Arrange(renderingRectangle);

element.EndInit();
element.UpdateLayout();
```

I added the `BeginInit()`, `EndInit()` and `UpdateLayout()` (though by process of elimination I believe `UpdateLayout()` is the key) and now the binding expressions in my dynamically-loaded xaml are working correctly. Hurrah!

Comment: It's not clear what you weren't doing before. What's the key bit?

Comment: Ahh yes in my excitement I forgot to make it clear. I've updated the answer now. :)